# A caught exception occurred while trying to draw a graph in Processing

Tags: raspberry-pi, processing, runtimeexception

while working with processing on raspberry pi I was attempting to have a second screen pop up with data I had gathered in a separate method. On short runs (about 1 minute or less), the code is able to make this without issue. On longer runs (above 1 minute) it pops up this error message:

`RunnableTask.run(): A caught exception occured on thread Animation Thread-Display-.x11_:0.0-2-EDT-1: RunnableTask[enqueued true[executed false, flushed false], tTotal 0 ms, tExec 0 ms, tQueue 0 ms, attachment null, throwable java.lang.RuntimeException: Waited 5000ms for: <127debe, 14323ef>[count 1, qsz 0, owner <Animation Thread-FPSAWTAnimator#00-Timer0>] - <Animation Thread-Display-.x11_:0.0-2-EDT-1>]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Waited 5000ms for: <127debe, 14323ef>[count 1, qsz 0, owner <Animation Thread-FPSAWTAnimator#00-Timer0>] - <Animation Thread-Display-.x11_:0.0-2-EDT-1>
    at jogamp.common.util.locks.RecursiveLockImpl01Unfairish.lock(RecursiveLockImpl01Unfairish.java:198)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.getLocationOnScreen(WindowImpl.java:1159)
    at jogamp.newt.driver.x11.X11UnderlayTracker.windowMoved(X11UnderlayTracker.java:141)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.consumeWindowEvent(WindowImpl.java:4386)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.sendWindowEvent(WindowImpl.java:4317)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.positionChanged(WindowImpl.java:4558)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.sizePosMaxInsetsVisibleChanged(WindowImpl.java:4865)
    at jogamp.newt.driver.x11.DisplayDriver.DispatchMessages0(Native Method)
    at jogamp.newt.driver.x11.DisplayDriver.dispatchMessagesNative(DisplayDriver.java:112)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.waitForVisible(WindowImpl.java:4449)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.waitForVisible(WindowImpl.java:4443)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.createNative(WindowImpl.java:777)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.setVisibleActionImpl(WindowImpl.java:1248)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl$VisibleAction.run(WindowImpl.java:1318)
    at com.jogamp.common.util.RunnableTask.run(RunnableTask.java:127)
    at jogamp.newt.DefaultEDTUtil$NEDT.run(DefaultEDTUtil.java:375)
DefaultEDT.run(): Caught exception occured on thread Animation Thread-Display-.x11_:0.0-2-EDT-1: RunnableTask[enqueued false[executed true, flushed false], tTotal 8481 ms, tExec 8481 ms, tQueue 0 ms, attachment null, throwable java.lang.RuntimeException: Waited 5000ms for: <127debe, 14323ef>[count 1, qsz 0, owner <Animation Thread-FPSAWTAnimator#00-Timer0>] - <Animation Thread-Display-.x11_:0.0-2-EDT-1>]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Waited 5000ms for: <127debe, 14323ef>[count 1, qsz 0, owner <Animation Thread-FPSAWTAnimator#00-Timer0>] - <Animation Thread-Display-.x11_:0.0-2-EDT-1>
    at jogamp.common.util.locks.RecursiveLockImpl01Unfairish.lock(RecursiveLockImpl01Unfairish.java:198)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.getLocationOnScreen(WindowImpl.java:1159)
    at jogamp.newt.driver.x11.X11UnderlayTracker.windowMoved(X11UnderlayTracker.java:141)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.consumeWindowEvent(WindowImpl.java:4386)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.sendWindowEvent(WindowImpl.java:4317)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.positionChanged(WindowImpl.java:4558)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.sizePosMaxInsetsVisibleChanged(WindowImpl.java:4865)
    at jogamp.newt.driver.x11.DisplayDriver.DispatchMessages0(Native Method)
    at jogamp.newt.driver.x11.DisplayDriver.dispatchMessagesNative(DisplayDriver.java:112)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.waitForVisible(WindowImpl.java:4449)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.waitForVisible(WindowImpl.java:4443)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.createNative(WindowImpl.java:777)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.setVisibleActionImpl(WindowImpl.java:1248)
    at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl$VisibleAction.run(WindowImpl.java:1318)
    at com.jogamp.common.util.RunnableTask.run(RunnableTask.java:127)
    at jogamp.newt.DefaultEDTUtil$NEDT.run(DefaultEDTUtil.java:375)`

After displaying this message it does graph the data without issue, but I have no clue as to why this error is occurring. I'm sorry for my ignorance on this I am still pretty new to coding. If you have any ideas onto how or why this is happening, as well as any possible fixes it would be GREATLY appreciated. My full code can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fw4lzk7to77xu2w/AACrpVnWW4Jq9MFzKa5uzLEfa?dl=0) Though I believe the error is coming from the "Second_Screen" file, I included the whole code just in case. Thank you again for any help, it is very appreciated!

Also if you need any additional information please let me know! I'm sorry if i forgot anything necessary.

Comment: Please link between crossposts. This question was also asked [here](https://discourse.processing.org/t/a-caught-error-exception-occurred-on-raspberry-pi/1129).

Comment: Hi sorry about that Kevin I will make sure to do so in the future!

Answer (score 0):

In my "Second Screen File" I use this line:

```
window2 = GWindow.getWindow(this, "Window title", 25, 25, 855, 510, P2D);
```

By changing it to

```
window2 = GWindow.getWindow(this, "Window title", 25, 25, 855, 510, JAVA2D);
```

The error is resolved at the time I am testing on longer and longer runs, but it hasn't given me any errors yet. I'm not sure the difference between JAVA2D and P2D but it doesn't really matter as I'm just glad the error is resolved.